# Could not load com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask. java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I am working with a Mobile web application, where for the database part i am using `Hibernate` and for the connection pooling `c3p0`, when i am running the application in the beginning its working fine, but after did some transaction like select, save, update, i am getting the following exception, i don't know why its happening,

```
Sep 22, 2015 12:40:06 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1562)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1040)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.removeResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1507)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.removeResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1477)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.cullExpired(BasicResourcePool.java:1565)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$1900(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$CullTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:2089)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
Exception in thread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2sa3m19b1vnwmg61s8v1zi|5363e54]-AdminTaskTimer" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/resourcepool/BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1040)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.removeResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1507)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.removeResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1477)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.cullExpired(BasicResourcePool.java:1565)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$1900(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$CullTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:2089)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    ... 8 more
```

**Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.password">admin</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">com.bss.util.PostgreSQLDialectCustom</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Use the C3P0 connection pool provider -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

    <mapping class="com.bss.model.TestUser"/>
    <mapping class="com.bss.model.ItappFriendlist"/>
    <mapping class="com.bss.model.ItappFriendlistPK"/>
    <mapping class="com.bss.model.User"/>   
    <mapping class="com.bss.model.UserSession"/>    
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, you are hitting tomcat hot-redeploy `ClassLoader` issues.

There are two things you should do:

1. Make sure that when your application is shutdown, your Hibernate `SessionFactory` gets `close()`ed as well. The best place to do this is a `ServletContextListener`. Otherwise, on hot redeploy, c3p0 Threads from a now-discarded app will continue to be running. See [SessionFactory.close()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#close--)
2. Try the settings described [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#tomcat-specific) to prevent stray references to objects from a defunct `ClassLoader`. You can just add

---

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.privilegeSpawnedThreads">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.contextClassLoaderSource">library</property>
```

---

to your c3p0 config section.

(p.s. Be sure you are using a recent version of c3p0. These settings are new-ish.)

Comment: So this problem should not happen on production enviroments, right?